# Can I redefine a ContentPage to add some elements to it?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

My application uses many ContentPages like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
         xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
         x:Class="Japanese.Views.HelpTab.SettingsPage" 
         Title="Settings Screen Help" 
         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Spacing="0">
           <Content goes here/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Is there a way that I could create a new type of page called `ScrollableContentPage` that already has the `<ScrollView>` and `<StackLayout Spacing="0">` elements?

Something like this:

```
<ScrollableContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
         xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
         x:Class="Japanese.Views.HelpTab.SettingsPage" 
         Title="Settings Screen Help" 
         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}">
<ContentPage.Content>
   <Content goes here/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that there are several possibilities. We are using a nested `ContentView` that is bound to the inner content. Just add the `ContentView` the XAML of the page you'd like to reuse

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
         xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
         x:Class="Japanese.Templates.ScrollableContentPage" 
         BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource PageBackgroundColor}"
         x:Name="ContentPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView>
            <ContentView Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentPage}, Path=InnerContent}" />
        </ScrollView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And in the code behind you'll have to define a bindable property (actually I don't know if it **has** to be a bindable property, but you'll need the change notification anyway, hence a `BindableProperty` should be fine)

```
public static readonly BindableProperty InnerContentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(InnerContent), typeof(View), typeof(ScrollableContentPage));

public View InnerContent
{
    get => (View)this.GetValue(InnerContentProperty);
    set => this.SetValue(InnerContentProperty, value);
}
```

Now you can use the `ScrollableContentPage` as you would use any other page (well, you need the namespace imports, but ...)

```
<template:ScrollableContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
     xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
     x:Class="Japanese.Views.HelpTab.SettingsPage" 
     Title="Settings Screen Help">
    <template:ScrollableContentPage.InnerContent>
        <!-- You content goes here -->
    </template:ScrollableContentPage.InnerContent>
</template:ScrollableContentPage>
```

You can even simplify this, by adding the attribute to `ScrollableContentPage`.

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(InnerContent))]
public class ScrollableContentPage : ContentPage
{
    // ...
}
```

This way you can omit specifiing `InnerContent` explicitly and use your `ScrollableContentPage` like this:

```
<template:ScrollableContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese" 
     xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
     x:Class="Japanese.Views.HelpTab.SettingsPage" 
     Title="Settings Screen Help">
    <!-- You content goes here -->
</template:ScrollableContentPage>
```

Comment: I almost wrote the answer when I saw yours! Well written by the way!

Comment: @G.hakim Thank you very much. Yeah, I know how frustrating it can be. Taking your time to write a detailed answer and right before posting it, someone was a µ faster :/ Sorry, man.

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the great answer. Could you just explain in a bit more detail for me.  Where should I add "[ContentProperty(nameof(InnerContent))]"  Thanks

Comment: @Alan2: Please see my edit. You just add it right above your class declaration.

Comment: @PaulKertscher - I tried your code but I am having some problems and getting a null exception.  Can you explain to me what AssistantPageBase is and what I should be using in my code for that?  Should I replace that with ScrollableContentPage?  If that's the case then I did that and when the code runs it points to the "      <ContentView Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference ContentPage}, Path=InnerContent}">" line and says there is a null exception.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alan2 I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Alan2 Please see my edit. I've had several minor errors in my code. Forgot the `x:Name="ContentPage"` in the XAML for `ScrollableContentPage` and had some of our class names in the definition of the bindable property. Does it work now? (It does for me in a new project)

Comment: Works now.  Thanks very much.

Comment: @Alan2 Glad I could help.